# Append New String at position of another string

Tags: javascript

I have two variables and need to insert string `b` into string `a` at the point after `href`.

```
var a = '<a href="http://pix6.agoda.net/">Image Credit</a>';
var b = 'rel="nofollow noreferrer noopener"';
```

The result I'm looking for is

```
<a href="http://pix6.agoda.net/" rel="nofollow noreferrer noopener">Image Credit</a>
```

How can I do this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

You could insert the `b` string after the `href` using the JavaScript [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function, i.e.:

```js
let a = '<a href="http://pix6.agoda.net/">Image Credit</a>';
let b = 'rel="nofollow noreferrer noopener"';
let h = 'href="';
let i = a.indexOf(h);
if (i > -1) {
  let j = a.indexOf('"', i + h.length);
  if (j > -1) {
    let c = a.substr(0, j + 1) + ' ' + b + a.substr(j + 1);
    console.log(c);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, trying to manipulate HTML by ripping apart and gluing strings together is a nasty, error-prone business.

Use DOM manipulation instead.

```js
var html = '<a href="http://pix6.agoda.net/">Image Credit</a>';

const domparser = new DOMParser();
const doc = domparser.parseFromString(`<div>${html}</div>`, "text/html");
const link = doc.querySelector("a");
link.setAttribute("rel", "nofollow noreferrer noopener");
const output = doc.querySelector("div").innerHTML;
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

To combine the strings you can use

```
 a.slice(0,a.indexOf(">")) + b + a.slice(a.indexOf(">"))
```

however, you should not do that to create a DOM node

Answer (score 2):

One more way

```
var a = '<a href ="http://pix6.agoda.net/">Image Credit</>'
var b = 'rel="nofollow noreferrer noopener">'
var d = a.split('>')[0]
var e = a.split('>')[1]
var x = d +' '+b +e 
console.warn(x)
```